# How does spin $j$ matter contribute to the running of the gauge coupling?

Tags: quantum-spin, gauge-theory, renormalization, yang-mills

The one-loop beta function $\beta(g)$ for the gauge coupling $g$ with gauge group $G=SU(N_c)$, in a theory with $n_f$ spin-1/2 fermions in a representation $R_f$ of $G$, and $n_s$ complex scalars in a representation $R_s$, takes the form

$$\beta(g)=-\Big(\frac{11}{3}C_2(G)-\frac{1}{3}n_sT(R_s)-\frac{4}{3}n_fT(R_f)\Big)\frac{g^3}{16\pi^2}.$$

Where $C_2(G)$, $T(R_s)$, and $T(R_f)$ are Casimir invariants. Is it known how massive particles with arbitrary spin $j$ in some representation $R_j$ of $G$, contribute to the one-loop beta function?

Comment: Higher spin charged particles generally produce a nonrenormalizable theory, making the meaning of the $\beta$-function different in rather profound way from what you have with just $j\leq 1$.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. The values of Casimir constants are different for the different representations of the groups. So, you would need to add all the different terms for all the different particles.

Comment: @Buzz The beta function is defined regardless of the renormalizeability of the theory.

Comment: Suggestion: Consider for clarity to include the Lagrangian of the theory.